# Asp.net c# wikipedia query

Tags: c#

How can I convert Gujarati language in wikipedia? I want to develop an application like wiki and convert my whole page to Gujarati in language translator. How can I do so?

Comment: Not enough question marks to count as a real question.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_Machine_Translation_Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look....

http://gu.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%AA%AE%E0%AB%81%E0%AA%96%E0%AA%AA%E0%AB%83%E0%AA%B7%E0%AB%8D%E0%AA%A0

take a look again....
http://gu.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%AA%97%E0%AB%81%E0%AA%9C%E0%AA%B0%E0%AA%BE%E0%AA%A4%E0%AB%80_%E0%AA%AD%E0%AA%BE%E0%AA%B7%E0%AA%BE

google provide gujarati api... just see that.

http://www.google.com/transliterate/

Answer (score 3):

you should use the google language api, its free to use and supports gujarati. :)

http://code.google.com/apis/language/

Hope this helps,
Eamonn

Comment: +1 - if I could give a +.5, I would have due to use of _should_ above _could_.